# How to make the background transparent in fullscreen mode (in OpenGL)?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I want to create a transparent background, but it only works if the 4th (monitor) parameter is set to NULL. If I modify the window to be fullscreen (as the code shows below) the background just turns to black without any transparency. Is there any solution?

Note: I only want the background to be transparent. Not the whole window with its content.

```
//at configuring  
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);       

...  

//at window creation  
GLFWmonitor* primary = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();  
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Application",primary, NULL);

...

//in render loop  
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: One of the main points of all that "exclusive fullscreen" shenanigans on windows is to bypass the desktop compositor (to get rid of the extra latency and also of an extra copy step), and if you bypass the compositor, transparency doesn't make sense any more, because there is no background, and no instance which could blend your output over that background.

Comment: @derhass So the main problem was that I didn't understand how fullscreen really works and what it does with the composition. Now I've managed to run the application in a borderless window with the glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GL_FALSE); hint, and it works just like I imagined. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tryed something and is look like transparent is working by default if you have transparent supported on OS theme (some windows 7 themes are just solid colors so be carefoul because your OS theme will disable OS transparence support).

**main.cpp** file:

```
// INCLUDE
#include "main.h"

// DECLARATION
static void key_event(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int);

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
int app_width = 512;
int app_height = 256;

// RUN
void main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit()) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, GLFW_TRUE);

    GLFWmonitor* monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(mode->width, mode->height, "GLFW Test", monitor, NULL);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_event);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &app_width, &app_height);
        glViewport(0, 0, app_width, app_height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // TO DO
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static void key_event(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) { 
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE); 
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

**main.h** file:

```
#pragma once

// INCLUDE
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

For me is working. (I see if the **glClearColor** have not full **0.0f** value, the background will not be complet transparente...